# How does the Link Amp mod affect the maximum link range for portals in Ingress?

Tags: ingress

The Link Amp mod is now available to be installed on portals. However, its leaked description only mentions that it increases the maximum link distance, without providing any numbers. So...

What is the exact effect of a Link Amp mod on the maximum linking distance? Is the effect cumulative if several Link Amp mods are installed?

Also - this will be harder to test until we will start getting the mods from regular hacks, but do these mods have 'levels' such as shields? Very Rare Link Amps allow to create longer links than Rare Link Amps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct information is:

- First = +1x range
- Second = +0.5x range
- Third = +0.25x range
- Fourth = +0.25x range
- Total max is +2x (3x the original length)

Answer (score 5):

The first one doubles the max distance. With every deployed Link Amplifier you get less and less benefit from them, so you should deploy better one first to be more efficient. This is a way to discourage deployment of same mods on portal.

- First one = +1x range
- Second one = +0.5x range
- Third one = +0.25x range
- Fourth one = +0.25x range
- Total max is +2x (3x the original length)

taken from: http://decodeingress.me/ingress-manual/ingress-items/portal-mods/link-amplifier/

Comment: When you say +2x, do you mean the outcome is "times two" or actually "plus double"? It looks to me like the signage here is inconsistent. The first is probably 2x, the second 1.5x, etc. That or use +1, +.5, etc. Unless the first actually triples the distance!

Comment: The third and fourth linkamps have the same amount of amplification according to the decodeingress article you've provided which is +0.25x range.

Comment: @Flaunting your last edit on the "Fourth one" line isn't correct. The fourth Linkamp's amplification is same as the third one.

Comment: Actually the first one is the one with best quality, not the one in leftmost slot. - Tested with multihacks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [decodeingress article on linkamps](http://decodeingress.me/ingress-manual/ingress-items/portal-mods/link-amplifier/) one VR Linkamp does extend the portal's range to 3.5 times. (Deduced from the 10.5 times calculation for the max possible range calculation, 10.5/3=3.5) So a single VR Linkamp takes the range amplification about the same amplification where 4 rare Linkamps do stop which is 3x.

Again according to the same article the max available link range is now 655.36 km * 10.5 = 6881.28 km with 4 VR linkamps.